# giving error on using localhost on twitter application built with mvc

Tags: twitter, localhost, x-callback-url

i am using using identity 2.0 OAuth in my web app ... 
when i enter http://localhost:61089/ in application setting :
it is giving error invalid URL format  format

values entered  here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is not a publicly-accessible URL so it is not a valid value in the website field.

Comment: Are you implementing sign-in with Twitter? i.e. does your app need to redirect back somewhere after a user has signed-in? if so, then use a publicly accessible URL there. If not, you can leave it blank. Only the website URL (i.e. your product or app's landing page on the web) is mandatory.

Comment: yup i want to redirect to my app ... after external login with twitter i need to redirect it to my dashboard ... with twitter user details including acces token and email mainly